# file upload in sails

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, angular-file-upload

i want to know, how to use upload files code in sails using angular upload

this is code for angular

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['angularFileUpload']);

        app.controller('ImageCtrl', ['$scope', '$upload', function ($scop

e, $upload) {
        $scope.$watch('files', function () {
            $scope.upload($scope.files);
        });

        $scope.upload = function (files) {

          window.alert(JSON.stringify(files));
            if (files && files.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var file = files[i];
                    $upload.upload({
                        url: '???????',
                        fields: {
                            'username': $scope.username
                        },
                        file: file
                    }).progress(function (evt) {
                        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' +
                                    evt.config.file.name);
                    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' +
                                    JSON.stringify(data));
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

in above code , what i should give url ? , my requirement is, i want to upload files in locally using sails  mongodb.

**Any one please share the server side nodejs code..**

Answer (score 0):

Sails have built-in streaming file uploads utility called [skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper). In general you can upload files from angular to any sails endpoint. Then you just need to perform something like this in your controller:

```
req.file('avatar').upload(function (err, uploadedFiles){
    if (err) return res.send(500, err);
    return res.send(200, uploadedFiles);
});
```

You can also pass skipper [options](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper#options):

```
req.file('avatar').upload({
    // ...any other options here...
}, ...);
```

If you aplication should upload files frequently I would recommend you to create service for this based on skipper API.